# Re: WHat have they done to WPF in Core 5.0 - Cannot display menuitem icons\images

Tags: wpf, icons, menuitem

I have been attempting to convert a .NET 4.8 WPF application to .NET Core 5.0 (I had to uninstall VS 2022 as it messed up my VS 2019 environment).

My main window's XAML code works just fine in all of the .NET Frameworks I have compiled the project to, including .NET Framework 4.8.

However, when I run my application under .NET Core 5.0, all of the menu-item icons\images are missing.

I have tried everything I could research to see if I did something wrong with a WPF 5.0 Workbench Application just to test out some of the menu's XAML and nothing has worked.

I can't even get an image to display in a grid where I specify the row specifically.

What am I missing here?

My Workbench Code is below.

Thank you for any assistance anyone would be able to provide...

**<<`>>`**

```
    <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFWorkbenchCore5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="450" 
        Width="800">

    <Grid>

    

        <Menu Grid.Row="0"  Name="mnuMasterMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Background="DarkSlateBlue" AllowDrop="True" Height="34" Visibility="Visible">
                <MenuItem Name="mnuAvailableFunctions" Header="Available Functions" Background="DarkSlateBlue" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/AvailableFunctions_128x128.png" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
    
        </Grid>
    
    </Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, changing my research terms to simply that of WPF and image issues,it appears I found the answer to my own question.

When I tested images outside of the menu system and they still weren't displayed, I realized that the issue was with image display alone and did not have anything to do with the menu system as I had initially thought.

In any event, when using .NET Core 5.0+ and you want to display an image anywhere, you must go into an image's properties and ensure that it is compiled as a "Resource" and that it is "Copied to the Output Directory".

With the 4. x.NET Frameworks this was never necessary as it was either assumed by the frameworks or simply used understood by the framework as an image to be displayed.

With so much lost in the new .NET Core Frameworks when compared to the 4.x frameworks, I wonder how many professionals are really rushing to use these new versions?

For my own work I see no advantages to them...

Comment: It's a typical mistake when using image in either .NET Framework 4.8 or .NET 6.0

Comment: Be aware that image files with Build Action Resource *do not* need to be copied to the Output Directory. They are built into the output assembly. For *"with the 4. x.NET Frameworks this was never necessary"*, it actually was, it was just the default setting. Also note that what you are talking about is called .NET 5.